# Multiple Portal Content Export/Backup

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I have multiple portals on my DNN host, each with their own set of 2SXC Content/Apps.  Is there a way to export content/apps from all portals without having to go into each portal separately?  I don't necessarily want to back up an entire server, when the only thing that has changed is perhaps some content on the site.

The reason this has come up is because I recently had a site that has become unreachable.  It exists on the server, but does not respond to any requests.  Since I cannot log into the site, I cannot backup their 2SXC Content & Apps.  And the only way to do a proper backup across all sites is to image the entire server and database.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to export everything, BUT you can cheat :)

If you open an App-Admin-Dialog (or the "Manage All Apps" dialog) with Shift-Click, you'll get a new window and that will contain a zone-id and app-id in the URL. You can mess with these to actually point to the other portal / app and do an export from there.

But you may run into problems when exporting - because some paths may be wrong. But I would give it a try before you do anything else.